# Create post and upload image with Ajax (axios) in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, axios, advanced-custom-fields

So I want my users to be able to create a post in the frontend and upload an image with a form I've created.
When the image is uploaded I want to update an ACF-field with the uploaded image.
I've seen some posts on this but none of them are explained any good.
I want to use Ajax and I want to use axios, so please no jQuery. I also use Qs.

The image itself is never uploaded but the file name is inserted in the media library.
Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="register-store-form">
    <fieldset class="store-images mb-3">
        <label for="store-images">Add images</label>
        <input type="file" id="store_images" name="store_images" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="update-store">Save store</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
const Qs = require('qs');
const axios = require('axios');
const saveStoreBtn = document.querySelector('#update-store');
const addStore = document.querySelector('#add-one-more-store');

function saveStore(e) {
   const storeName = document.querySelector('#store-name');
   const storeImages = document.querySelector('#store_images');
   const storeImageFile = storeImages.files[0];

   const ajaxData = {
       action : 'create_store',
       security : shkGlobal.addStore,
       name : storeName.value,
       image_name : storeImageFile.name,
       image_type : storeImageFile.type,
       description : storeDescription.value
   };

   axios.post(shkGlobal.adminUrl, Qs.stringify(ajaxData))
       .then(function(response) {
           saveStoreBtn.innerHTML = "Thank you";
   })
   .catch(err => console.log('Not working', err));
};

updateStoreBtn.addEventListener('click', saveStore);
```

**PHP**

```
function create_store() {
    check_ajax_referer('add_store', 'security');

    $name_value = $_POST['name'];
    $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];
    $image_type = $_POST['image_type'];
    
    $post_data = array(
        'post_type' => 'store',
        'post_title' => htmlentities($name_value),
        'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
        'post_status'   => 'draft'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$image_name];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ($movefile) {
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'].'/'.$image_name,
            'post_mime_type' => $image_type,
            'post_title' => $image_name,
            'post_content' => 'File '.$image_name,
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $movefile['file']);
        update_field('field_602019eba7767', $attach_id, $post_id);
    }

    echo json_decode($response);
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_create_store', 'create_store');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_store', 'create_store');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your case, first one that you are uploading multiple files, so structure of $_FILES will be different. Second one is that you specified `store_images` instead `store_images[]` for multiple file upload.

So in html change `<input type="file" name="store_images" multiple>` to `<input type="file" name="store_images[]" multiple>`

And in php, change your code accordingly to example below.

```
$files = $_FILES['store_images];
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {            
        if ($files['name']) { 
            $file = array( 
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );

            wp_handle_upload($file);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I'm testing the code I've only tried uploading one image. Is this still the problem? Shouldn't it only be the problem if I actually try uploading multiple images?